# Is Cassandra collection data type good for thousand items?

Tags: cassandra

I need to store java build dependencies in Cassandra.
A typical java project will have hundreds of dependencies, maximum of thousands.
My table is like this:

```
artifact_id text,
name text,
version text,
dependencies map<text, text>
```

Is it ok to store thousands of items in the Cassandra map data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not.  Collections work best for < 100 items.  Something in the line of thousands of items should be accommodated as a part of the data model.